# Custom Tkinter send values only on release

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

Im writing a script, which sends the values from the sliders via an array to the serial port. The problem is that if I change the value of the slider every single step is written into the array. I have no idea how I can send the last value of the slider (when you release it) to the array so that I got following structure: `[valueX, valueY, valueZ]`.

```
from tkinter import *
import customtkinter
import serial.tools.list_ports
import time

ports = []
for port in serial.tools.list_ports.comports():
    ports.append(port.name)

customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("System")  # Modes: system (default), light, dark
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("blue")  # Themes: blue (default), dark-blue, green
customtkinter.deactivate_automatic_dpi_awareness()

app = customtkinter.CTk()  # create CTk window like you do with the Tk window
app.geometry("560x550")
app.title('Scara Controller')

serialData = []

def slider_event_X(valueX):
    #print("X", valueX)
    Dynamic_label1.configure(text=round(valueX))

    serialData.append(valueX)

def slider_event_Y(valueY):
    #print("Y", valueY)
    Dynamic_label2.configure(text=round(valueY))

    serialData.append(valueY)

def slider_event_Z(valueZ):
    #print("Z", valueZ)
    Dynamic_label3.configure(text=round(valueZ))

    serialData.append(valueZ)

def button_event():
    print("Button pressed")
    print(serialData)

COM1 = customtkinter.StringVar(value="COM1")
def optionmenu_callback(choice):
    print("clicked:", choice)

combobox = customtkinter.CTkOptionMenu(master=app, values=ports, command=optionmenu_callback, variable=COM1)
combobox.place(x=220, y=20)


label0 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(app, text="COM Port wählen:", fg_color="transparent", font=("Arial", 20))
label0.place(x=50, y=20)

label1 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(app, text="X", fg_color="transparent")
label1.place(x=50, y=70)

label2 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(app, text="Y", fg_color="transparent")
label2.place(x=50, y=120)

label3 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(app, text="Z", fg_color="transparent")
label3.place(x=50, y=170)

Dynamic_label1 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(app, text="180", fg_color="transparent")
Dynamic_label1.place(x=380, y=70)

Dynamic_label2 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(app, text="180", fg_color="transparent")
Dynamic_label2.place(x=380, y=120)

Dynamic_label3 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(app, text="180", fg_color="transparent")
Dynamic_label3.place(x=380, y=170)

slider1 = customtkinter.CTkSlider(master=app, from_=0, to=360, width=300,command=slider_event_X)
slider1.place(x=70, y=75)

slider2 = customtkinter.CTkSlider(master=app, from_=0, to=360, width=300,command=slider_event_Y)
slider2.place(x=70, y=125)

slider3 = customtkinter.CTkSlider(master=app, from_=0, to=360, width=300,command=slider_event_Z)
slider3.place(x=70, y=175)

entryX = entry = customtkinter.CTkEntry(app, placeholder_text="Angle for X", width=80)
entryX.place(x=430, y=70)

entryY = entry = customtkinter.CTkEntry(app, placeholder_text="Angle for Y", width=80)
entryY.place(x=430, y=120)

entryZ = entry = customtkinter.CTkEntry(app, placeholder_text="Angle for Z", width=80)
entryZ.place(x=430, y=170)

button1 = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=app, text="Send", command=button_event)
button1.place(x=250, y=250)

print(serialData)

app.mainloop()
```

I tried to use an if statement like that:

```
if valueX not in serialData:
    serialData.append(valueX)
```

That didn´t work at all and I tried to use the way just like in tkinter, but that didnt work either

```
self.slider = tk.Scale(self.root, from_=0, to=256, 
                               orient="horizontal")
        self.slider.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.updateValue)
```

Comment: You don't need to create `serialData` initially.  Just create it inside `button_event()` with the values get from the sliders.

Comment: Use the ```CTkSlider.get()``` method.